# My kendo grid validation not work if i used Editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is my code in which i used the drop down in my kendo grid single column and i have used Editor template , foreign key column but none of these work according to my choice...
that is my code check

-Editor template column

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.Table_ID).ClientTemplate("#= Table_ID #" +
                      "<input type='hidden' name='PrevilegeViewModels[#= index(data)#].Table_ID' value='#= Table_ID #' />"
                  ).EditorTemplateName("Table").Title("Table").Width(300);
```

foreign key column

```
 columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Table_ID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.Table, "ID", "Name").ClientTemplate("#= Table_ID #" +
                   "<input type='hidden' name='PrevilegeViewModels[#= index(data)#].Table_ID' value='#= Table_ID #' />"
                   );
```

that is my Editor column in which i initilized a kendo dropdown Please

```
@using System.Collections

@model System.Int32

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()

.BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewBag.Table)

.OptionLabel("------------- Select Table -------------- ")

.DataValueField("ID")

.DataTextField("Name")

)
```

And these are two models

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int User_ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter First Name")]
        public string User_FN { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter Middle Name")]
        public string User_MN { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter Last Name")]
        public string User_LN { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter Login ID")]
        public string User_Login { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Enter PassWord")]
        public string User_Password { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please Select a Valid Role")]
        public int User_Role_ID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<PrevilegeViewModel> PrevilegeViewModels { get; set; }
    }
```

and another

```
public class PrevilegeViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Previleges_ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(1,UInt32.MaxValue)]
        public int Table_ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool P_Add { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool P_Edit { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool P_Delete { get; set; }        
    }
```

and when i didn't select any value grid show 0 but i provide the range b/w 1 to int32.max... 
Please check the code..